# d3.js: Stacked Bar Chart with low values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stacked-chart

I faced with a problem when some values in a bar very small when at the same time most of the other values are big enough. As the result these chunks with low values are almost not visible. I did not find any solution hot to correctly round chunks(not manually because I now that I can round them to more higher values via scale + invert(in order to determine what values I needed to show them more or less visible)). As an example below: as you see the last bar with low values is almost not visible. So can you suggest how to fix it? It would be great to have an opportunity to be able to specify the min size of stacked bar chart chunk. Thank you in advance.
http://jsfiddle.net/vhcdt13x/

```
// Setup svg using Bostock's margin convention

var margin = {top: 20, right: 160, bottom: 35, left: 30};

var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


/* Data in strings like it would be if imported from a csv */

var data = [
  { year: "2006", redDelicious: "100", mcintosh: "150", oranges: "90", pears: "60" },
  { year: "2012", redDelicious: "1", mcintosh: "1", oranges: "1", pears: "1" }
];

var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;


// Transpose the data into layers
var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["redDelicious", "mcintosh", "oranges", "pears"].map(function(fruit) {
  return data.map(function(d) {
    return {x: parse(d.year), y: +d[fruit]};
  });
}));


// Set x, y and colors
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(dataset[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }))
  .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.02);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {  return d3.max(d, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; });  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var colors = ["b33040", "#d25c4d", "#f2b447", "#d9d574"];


// Define and draw axes
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(5)
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat( function(d) { return d } );

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);


// Create groups for each series, rects for each segment 
var groups = svg.selectAll("g.cost")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "cost")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

var rect = groups.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .on("mouseover", function() { tooltip.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { tooltip.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    var xPosition = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
    var yPosition = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 25;
    tooltip.attr("transform", "translate(" + xPosition + "," + yPosition + ")");
    tooltip.select("text").text(d.y);
  });


// Draw legend
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(30," + i * 19 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {return colors.slice().reverse()[i];});

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width + 5)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d, i) { 
    switch (i) {
      case 0: return "Anjou pears";
      case 1: return "Naval oranges";
      case 2: return "McIntosh apples";
      case 3: return "Red Delicious apples";
    }
  });


// Prep the tooltip bits, initial display is hidden
var tooltip = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("display", "none");

tooltip.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("opacity", 0.5);

tooltip.append("text")
  .attr("x", 15)
  .attr("dy", "1.2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold");
```

Comment: Hi Konstantin, a possible solution could be to add a brush to zoom functionality to zoom into the small bars. An example can be found here: https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/area_brushZoom.html

Comment: Good Idea, thanks. but can I achieve what was described above?

Comment: Yes you can. You just need to recalculate the `scales` depending upon the zoom and then reacalculate the `width`, `height`, `x` and `y` of the bar `rect`. You can even restrict the zoom to only the y-axis.